# Need .htaccess code for modifying site URL

Tags: .htaccess

I have a website running at `www.mywebsite.com`. What I want is that when any user types any of the following URLs:

`http://www.mywebsite.com`

`www.mywebsite.com`

`mywebsite.com`

It should be interpreted as `http://mywebsite.com`

I need .htaccess code to achieve this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mod rewrite to achieve this, try...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.your-website.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://your-website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```